# Extract records delimited by '|^' in PIG

Tags: regex, unix, hadoop, pattern-matching, apache-pig

How can i extracts fields delimited by `|^` in [pig](/questions/tagged/pig) .
Sample in put data :

```
Jack|^USA|^BMW|^
```

I have tried `myRegExLoader('(\\w)\\|^')`

but not working

Comment: Why not use `PigStorage('|^')`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
testRel = LOAD 'data.txt' using PigStorage('|^') AS (name:chararray, country:chararray, organization:chararray)
```